# Active Directory multiple environment solution

Tags: active-directory

What would be the best solution to control 3 different environment with one active directory? 
3 different rooms, each with 10 machines.
1. 192.168.0.x
2. 192.168.1.x
3. 192.168.2.x
All of them connects via CISCO ASA to a server with active directory on it.
Not quite sure how can i add all of them under different "groups" as in every room there are computer with the same names.
Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. This question is a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions. But if you post there, you will need to add more detail to your question, like what you mean by "control".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Gabriel. will do so.